# Disabling the "Wi-Fi networks available" on Samsung Galaxy S II (Sprint Epic Touch 4G) on ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-2

If I'm away from my saved Wi-fi networks, and have the Wi-Fi radio on, I'm always getting a "**Wi-Fi networks available**" notification. I can dismiss the notification, but then it comes back within a few minutes.

I can't figure out how to disable that notification. I'm on a Sprint Epic 4G Touch  (Sprint's variant of the Samsung Galaxy S II), recently updated to ICS.

I remember this being a simple setting in Gingerbread, but I can't find the appropriate setting in ICS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wi-Fi settings page, tap *menu* and choose *Advanced*. From the Advanced Wi-Fi settings, uncheck "Network notification". It's only for open networks, but those are the only ones that ICS on the Epic Touch 4G reports.